# Integration of SkyDrive in Android Apps?

Tags: android, onedrive

I need to upload files to sky drive directly from my android application.How the sky drive is integrated with my application.I had already seen the documentation given by Skydrive. But i don't know how to use it in my application .I had completed up to adding the sdk and referenced the compiled Android API source code in my Android project as shown in the documentation .Any suggestions and sample codes are welcomed.